# Refresh the content when it reaches to its end "div"

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-animate

I want my page to automatically refresh after it automatically scrolls down...Here's my code on how to automatically scroll up and down.

```
function scroll(speed) {
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, speed, function() {
    $(this).animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, speed);
});
}

speed = 25000;

scroll(speed)
setInterval(function(){scroll(speed)}, speed * 2);
```

Comment: explain little bit more

Comment: if it refreshes when it hits bottom then you won't get to see it return? you can add another complete function to your second animate, something like `function(){ location.reload(); }` so then you shouldn't need your setInterval call.

Comment: So you mean @Sam0, I will replace setInterval(function(){scroll(speed)}, speed * 2); to function(){ location.reload(); } ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a quick fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/manoeuvres/LbLaf8La/ added the refresh call `location.reload();` in the 'action complete' function of your second animation call, so it refreshes when the animation returns to the top.

```
function scroll(speed) {
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, speed, function() {
    $(this).animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, speed, function(){ location.reload(); });
});
}

speed = 25000;

scroll(speed)
setInterval(function(){scroll(speed)}, speed * 2); // because the page is refreshing I don't think this line gets to get called. but no problem to leave it in.
```